# Understanding `man ls` long format: set-user-id and set-group-id modes

Tags: c, unix, permissions

I'm trying to re-create the UNIX `ls` in C as part of an exercise for school. It has to support the `-l` option entirely and behave just like the original.

By the way, I'm on OSX 10.8, if that makes any difference.

I'm having trouble understanding this part of the `MAN`, from the *Long Format* section. Specifically, I'm wondering if the two `if`s  on the same lines are `IF ... OR IF ...` or `IF ... AND IF ...`:

```
The first of the following that applies:

S     If in the owner permissions, the file is not executable and set-user-ID mode is set.  If in the group permissions, the file is not executable and set-group-ID mode is set.

s     If in the owner permissions, the file is executable and set-user-ID mode is set.  If in the group permissions, the file is executable and setgroup-ID mode is set.
```

As I understand it from the `man 2 stat` page, I can check for set-user-id mode like:

```
st_mode & 4000
```

And set-group-id mode like this:

```
st_mode & 2000
```

So how can I check if both are set? If `st_mode & 2000` is true, `st_mode & 4000` has to be false right?

Comment: You should probably use the predified constants S_IRUSR, S_IRGRP etc instead of magic numbers like 2000 and 4000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm having trouble understanding this part of the MAN, from the Long Format section.
>   Specifically, I'm wondering if the two ifs on the same lines are IF ... OR IF ... or IF ... AND IF ...

The IFs are independent. A file can have the setuid bit on or off, and it can also have the setgid bit on or off. The description in the `ls` man page can be a bit confusing because the wording is so concise. Here's a description that will hopefully be clearer. Refer to the [stat.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html) man page for the bit definitions.

- First, consider the owner bits and the setuid bit.

  - If the owner read bit is on, output `r`, else output `-`.
  - If the owner write bit is on, output `w`, else output `-`.
  - If the owner executable bit is off and the setuid bit is on, output `S`, else if the owner executable bit is on and the setuid bit is on, output `s`, else if the owner executable bit is on, output `x`, else output `-`.
- Next, consider the group bits and the setgid bit.

  - If the group read bit is on, output `r`, else output `-`.
  - If the group write bit is on, output `w`, else output `-`.
  - If the group executable bit is off and the setgid bit is on, output `S`, else if the group executable bit is on and the setgid bit is on, output `s`, else if the group executable bit is on, output `x`, else output `-`.
- Next, consider the other bits and the S_ISVTX bit.

  - If the other read bit is on, output `r`, else output `-`.
  - If the other write bit is on, output `w`, else output `-`.
  - If the file is a directory and the other executable bit is off and the S_ISVTX bit is on, output `T`, else if the file is a directory and the other executable bit is on and the S_ISVTX bit is on, output `t`, else if the other executable bit is on, output `x`, else output `-`.
  - In some versions of UNIX, the "if the file is a directory" requirement is omitted, and `T` or `t` can be output for ordinary files if the other requirements are met.

HISTORICAL PERSPECTIVE

Originally, the setuid, setgid, and save-text bits were only meaningful for executable files, so the long format `ls` could get away with replacing the `x` tags with `s` or `t`, and it was understood that the `x` tag was implied. Later revisions of UNIX allowed the setuid, setgid, and save-text bits to have different semantics for non-executable files and for directories (generally, file locking, inheritance of a directory's group by new files, and restricted deletion), so the `S` and `T` tags were added to `ls`'s output.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if two (or more) bits are set by comparing the result of the masking with the mask:

```
(st_mode & 0x6000) == 0x6000
```

Comment: Or (st_mode & 0x6000) != 0

Comment: @Quirliom That won't work, as the result would be non-zero even if only one of the bits were set.

Comment: Ah. Right you are. Silly me.